# Having problems since latest (0.5.3) Meteor update?

Tags: meteor

I just updated Meteor and now suddenly all my applications throw the following error when trying to run them:

```
app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:32
      throw err;
            ^
Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:3002]
    at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:482:73)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:123:20)
    at connection.on._self._poolState (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:96:15)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Socket.errorHandler (/usr/local/meteor/lib/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:411:10)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:93:17)
    at Socket._destroy.self.errorEmitted (net.js:328:14)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
Exited with code: 1
```

Any tips are welcome!
Thanks

Comment: Did you update, or uninstall/reinstall?

Comment: The updates aren't always stable. I would try uninstalling, then installing the new version fresh. It looks like it failed to remove an old driver.

Comment: Thanks, will try. Could you help me on how to make sure I uninstall everything correctly?

Comment: Perhaps you have a runaway mongo process that is getting in the way of launching new mongos on the right port. Try running 'killall mongod' or just rebooting to clear out old processes.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with my meteor app, rebooting did not fix it, but I will try uninstalling and reinstalling meteor

Comment: While this is happening, is a `mongod` process running (eg, check in ps auxww)?

Comment: No, there is no mongod process running. I also tried removing meteor and reinstalling. The problem persists.

Answer (score 8):

**Run `meteor update` to upgrade to 0.5.4**, which should fix it. See below to understand what was wrong.

This was a regression in Meteor 0.5.3. In development mode, Meteor runs `ps` in order to figure out if there's an existing `mongod` to kill before starting a new `mongod`. When making an unrelated bugfix, I added some misguided error checking to see if `ps` prints anything to standard error. Unfortunately, on OSX Mountain Lion, if `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (or several other environment variables starting with `DYLD`, or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) is set, then running `ps` prints a warning to stderr, causing Meteor 0.5.3 to consider `ps` to have failed. I [fixed this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/071b86900a1a917ac6e93451fa7c92691d6873cb) and released the fix in Meteor 0.5.4, thanks to this Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Thanks David, that worked! DYLD was being used by MySQL on my environment, as you pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, I had to use sudo to launch meteor server. In the past I didn't have to do this.

Comment: More specifically, in collaborative debugging Pent and I found that the problem is with ps producing some stderr, at least in the setup Pent was using to run it.  Meteor will see the stderr, assume something went wrong, and not start mongod.

Comment: Run `set` in the shell to list your environment variables. Do any of them begin with DYLD or LD?

Comment: Yes, I have an entry redefining DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, what does it refer to?

Comment: This solved my issue when I upgraded meteor and it would not start the server because it would give me an error when trying to connect to mongodb